# How to successfully call CQL in YSLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld, boundless-suite, cql, ysld

I am trying to create a web map using GeoServer, and doing styling via YSLD.

[According to YSLD documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/filters.html#ysld-reference-filters), I should be able to include CQL in order to do filtering.

For a test, I am using OpenStreetMap data from a PostGIS data store.  Here is some YSLD that works:

```
- name: name
  rules:
  - name: motorwaytrunkcasing
    filter: ${highway='motorway'}
    symbolizers:
    - line:
        stroke-color: '#440054'
        stroke-width: 5
```

No problem there.  However, when I add the following CQL:

```
filter: ${highway='motorway' AND other_tags NOT LIKE '%"tunnel"=>"yes"%' AND (other_tags LIKE '%"bridge"=>"yes"%' OR other_tags LIKE '%"bridge"=>"viaduct"%') AND other_tags LIKE '%"layer"=>"2"%'}
```

It fails with the following error:

```
${highway='motorway' AND other_tags NOT LIKE '%"tunnel"=>"yes"%' AND (other_tags LIKE '%"bridge"=>"yes"%' OR other_tags LIKE '%"bridge"=>"viaduct"%') AND other_tags LIKE '%"layer"=>"2"%'} symbolizers ^ Lexical error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""
```

I've copy-pasted this CQL to test it using OpenLayers on the same GeoServer, and it *is* valid; it correctly filters the data.

Might this be a bug?